# Calendly slowing website, because of script

Tags: html, calendly

After integrating Calendly into my website caused a decrease of page speed.

The first thing, I tried was to add **async** and **defer** at the end of script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" defer></script>
```

But it doesn't improve speed, so what should I do to improve the speed of page?

Comment: where do you load the script? if not, do it at the bottom of the page(just before the body closure), so it will be the last element loaded. This could be enought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have done it with javascript, and It improved speed from 40 to 80 points.
Basically that loads Calendly after a few seconds, so It doesn't slow the page at the beginning.

```
window.onload = function() {
 window.setTimeout(function () { 
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = 'https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js';
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
 }, 3000);
};
```